# oracle column heading interferes to another column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have problem with Oracle 10g database headig format.
I have this code

```
COLUMN id HEADING "Rodné|číslo" FORMAT A10
COLUMN name HEADING "Meno" FORMAT A20
COLUMN surname HEADING "Priezvisko" FORMAT A20
--some select here
```

Column id is char(10) type, other columns are varchar2(30) type. Result is this

```
Rodné
číslo    Meno           Priezvisko
---------- -------------------- --------------------
7951051548 Bohdana              Filcova
4054207561 Bohumila             Kmecova
```

As you can see header "Meno" interferes to first column and header "Priezvisko" interferes to second. I can't understand why. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a character set issue. SQL*Plus supports [globalisation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eleven.htm), so perhaps one of the characters you're using isn't in your session's characterset. If I set my NLS_LANG:

```
export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8ISO8859P1"

Rodné
číslo    Meno           Priezvisko
---------- -------------------- --------------------
7951051548 Bohdana              Filcova
4054207561 Bohumila             Kmecova
```

... then I get the same behaviour you do. (It's slightly modified, but not fixed by `set tab off`). If I change my session to UTF8 then it aligns properly:

```
export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.UTF8"

Rodné
číslo      Meno                 Priezvisko
---------- -------------------- --------------------
7951051548 Bohdana              Filcova
4054207561 Bohumila             Kmecova
```

This is in 11gR2, incidentally, so it isn't an Oracle 10g issue; my database character set is AL32UTF8. Also interesting is taking a dump of the value in each session, with 'select dump('Rodné|číslo', 1016) from dual'; with WE8ISO8859P1:

```
DUMP('RODNé|číSLO',1016)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=20 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 52,6f,64,6e,c3,83,c2,a9,7c,c3,84,c2,8d,c3,8
3,c2,ad,73,6c,6f
```

... and with UTF8:

```
DUMP('RODNÉ|ČÍSLO',1016)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=14 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 52,6f,64,6e,c3,a9,7c,c4,8d,c3,ad,73,6c,6f
```

Presumably with the former it thinks the output is taking up a bit more space than it actually is, so it isn't padding the heading quite right.

The `č` seems to be the problem. It is [defined in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm), but not in [WE8ISO8859P1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305167.aspx) or [WE8MSWIN1252](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145.aspx) (sourced from [here](http://arjudba.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/difference-between-we8iso8859p1-and.html)). In the Unicode version that's shown in the dump as `c4,8d`, and for the non-unicode it's building it from `c3,84,c2,8d`. Quite how and why that causes the effect you see is going beyond my understanding of character sets...